Angular, Directive - DOMException: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched
I am writing a directive for Input field in a form.
I want to show an empty string when the value is '*'
The values are coming from the backend and I want to bind the value.
My directive is working fine but I am also getting exception.
Code
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventType } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPassword]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class PasswordDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  private textbox!: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(
    private readonly el: ElementRef,
    private readonly renderer: Renderer2,
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.textbox =
      (this.el.nativeElement as HTMLElement).tagName === 'INPUT'
        ? (this.el.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement)
        : ((this.el.nativeElement as HTMLElement).querySelector('input') as HTMLInputElement);
  }

    @HostListener('change', ['$event']) onChange(): void {
    if (this.textbox === undefined || this.textbox.value !== '*') {
      return;
    } else {
      try {
        this.renderer.setProperty(this.textbox, 'value', '');
      } catch (e) {        
        // Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event is already being dispatched.
        // silence
      }
    }
  }
}

blue, input, keydown, keyup events are not helping when I bind the values. These events are helping only when I type. But my requirement is to change the value when I bind. I don't want to change the form value but only display value.
I truly appreciate any lead.
I tried settings up different events but not helping. Also I tried Pipe but no luck.
I want to change the display value not form value.

Remember if you're using Viewchild, you generally have a "ElementRef" (when you use a template reference variable inside the .html is the html tag, but it's not true when you're using in .ts), so, perhafs should be this.textbox.nativeElement (or use $event.target) wht about your this.textbox?

I have placed the code for entire directive
